# Is there a way to call parent's function synchronous?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, progressive-web-apps

How can I call a function in my parent that changes its state in a synchronous way?My application flow is like this:

first :

`this.props.parentProps.setSign(role, res.data["auth"]);`

then :

`this.props.params.history.push("/");`

when the URL change to `/` my parent state doesn't change and needs a browser refresh!

Answer (score 2):

Adjust your parent function `setSign` to accept a callback as 3rd param and pass it as second param of your setState
for eg:

```
setSign = (role, auth, cb) => {
  --------
  this.setState({'xx':'yy'}, cb)
  -------
}
```

Pass a callback to your parent component function like this, and do the route change in that callback

```
this.props.parentProps.setSign(role, res.data["auth"], () => {
  this.props.params.history.push("/");
});
```

Comment: I've done it but my problem still happened
after callback function :
`auth: null
role: null`